# VBA throwing run time error : 76 - Path Not Found

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, webdav, unc

I am trying to create a macro based VBA wherein the code will access sharepoint files do some file moving, copying as well as some data manipulation activities. While using UNC path for sharepoint folder, at times it works and sometimes it throws Runtime error 76: path not found.

The part of code where error is occuring is as follows:

```
Sub ConvertXLSBtoXLSX()
    Dim SharePointPath As String
    Dim SharePointFile As String
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim foundFile As Boolean
    Dim oldFilePath As String
    Dim newFilePath As String
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject

    Call AskForDate
    ' Specify the SharePoint file path and filename
    SharePointPath = "https://sites.xyz.com/sites/ABC/Shared Documents/Employee/"
    SharePointFile = "Data.xlsb"
    SharePointFolderPath = "\\sites.xyz.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\ABC\Shared Documents\Employee\"
    Const fileExtension As String = ".xlsb"
    
    Set folder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(SharePointFolderPath)
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If UCase(Right(file.Name, Len(fileExtension))) = UCase(fileExtension) Then
            oldFilePath = file.Path
            newFilePath = Left(oldFilePath, InStrRev(oldFilePath, "\")) & SharePointFile
            
            ' Rename the file
            Name oldFilePath As newFilePath
            
            foundFile = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next file

End Sub
```

If I open the sharepoint path in file explorer mode and run the code, it will work perfectly. This looks like some connection is getting disconnected in a day or at a frequency and me opening the driver in file explorer mode is enabling the connection.

Is there anyway I can make this automated such that I don't need to do this all the time manually?

Comment: The short answer is no. Microsoft are no longer supporting the WebDav (DavWWWRoot) method of accessing files. I currently have a similar problem and am running a VB script daily to open the URL invoked by 'Open in Explorer' but I'm not expecting it to work forever.

Comment: You can sync the folder and use the local path